# Locally added WCF webservice WSDL giving not find default endpoint element in that reference contract

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, svc

We added one WSDL locally from system and call the method from the same.
But below error is occurring when it executing

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract '' in
>   the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because
>   no configuration file was found for your application, or because no
>   endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client
>   element.

Config section

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICheckNewRequests" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://xxxxxx/xxx/xxx/xxx.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ICheckNewRequests"
                contract="xxx.ICheckNewRequests" name="BasicHttpBinding_ICheckNewRequests" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

what we are missing at config section

Answer (score 0):

What is the project template type of your client-side? the above configuration might not be generated by your latest operation of adding service reference. please remove the service reference and System.servicemode section in the configuration. then add it again to verify whether the service endpoint is generated by the last operation.
Besides, please pay attention to the Service contract. When we instantiate the client proxy, the namespace should correspond to the service contract of the endpoint.

```
ServiceReference1.ServiceClient client = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();
```

---

```
<endpoint address="https://vabqia969vm:6500/" binding="wsHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService" contract="ServiceReference1.IService"
    name="WSHttpBinding_IService" />
```

At last, if the operation of adding service reference doesn’t generate the client endpoint, it might due to that the WCF is Rest API instead of SOAP web service.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.